# How to insert a GORM model with deeply nested one-to-many models

Tags: go-gorm

I have 3 struct models corresponding to 3 DB tables.

Book model

```
type Book struct {
   ID      uuid.UUID
   Pages   []*Page
}
```

Page model

```
type Page struct {
   ID        uuid.UUID
   BookID    string
   PageNum   int
   Words     []*Word
}
```

Word model

```
type Word struct {
   ID       uuid.UUID
   PageID   uuid.UUID
   Letters  []byte
}
```

One Book can have many Pages. One Page can have many Words.

I am trying to insert a single hydrated Book struct into my Book table, and allow GORM to populate the several rows for the Page and Word tables. Based on the examples in the  [GORM has many documentation](https://gorm.io/docs/has_many.html#Polymorphism-Association) it seems this can be done with one `create()` call and association will be inferred by [the default naming convention](https://gorm.io/docs/has_many.html#Override-Foreign-Key). But when I call `db.Create(&hydratedBook)` only the Book table is inserted into.

Debug output:

```
INSERT  INTO "book" ("id","created_at","updated_at","delete_requested_at") 
VALUES ('95B9A964-7227-44B1-AA32-C5BCEDCE0857','2022-07-08 22:01:36','2022-07-08 22:01:36',NULL) 
RETURNING "book"."id"
```

Any feedback is greatly appreciated.